# exporting source code blocks from org mode fails

Tags: org-mode

I am trying to export an example like this to HTML

```
#+BEGIN_SRC sh
ls
#+END_SRC
```

I get this error

```
Wrong type argument: arrayp, sh-mode-default
```

with org-mode 9.4 (Aquamacs 3.5). I was expecting a nicely formatted html file. requiring 'ob-shell doesn't seem to change anything, but then again I don't want to execute anything, merely format.

As you can see I don't really understand defaults or what sh-mode-default is. An analogous error arises when I try other supported languages such as emacs-lisp.

I'll be grateful for any insight into what's misconfigured!

Comment: Maybe enable debug-on-error (`M-x toggle-debug-on-error RET`) to see where the error is happening. For the record, exporting this in v9.5 of org on Linux works just fine.

Comment: thank you, I have upgraded to org 9.5.2 within Aquamacs 3.6. When I export that troublesome example, I get this backtrace
```Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument arrayp sh-mode-default)
  nreverse(sh-mode-default)
  (mapcar (function (lambda (face) (if (symbolp face) (or (htmlize-get-override-fstruct face) (htmlize-face-to-fstruct-1 face)) (htmlize-attrlist-to-fstruct face)))) (nreverse face-list))
...
  org-export-to-file(html "troublesome.html" nil nil nil nil nil)
```

Comment: I've also tried deleting archive-contents as suggested [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/20380), to no avail

Comment: as Éric said, this same example works fine on linux. and also works correctly when I Start Aquamacs without customization. however I cannot figure out which of my customizations is causing the problem...

Comment: cleaning out a bunch of files named

customizations.1.8.el
customizations.2.0.el
customizations.2.1.el
customizations.3.0.el

has worked! with gratitude for the encouragement, -john